# .htaccess - removing extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink, seo

So, I've recently started rebuilding my website from scratch, and now I've gotten to the point where I should edit my .htaccess file to make the links more SEO-friendly, etc.

Currently, I am working on removing the .php, .html and other extensions from my webpages to get clean links. For example, I want: 
 
 http://www.mega.co.rs/founder.php
 
to become
 
    http://www.mega.co.rs/founder
 
 
Writing `Options +MultiViews` in my .htaccess file seems to solve the problem, when I navigate between the pages of my domain. However, when I open my browser, and go directly to the 'corrected' link, it gives me a the first link, with the extension. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Put your `.htaccess` file content here.

Comment: @undone I've edited the question... Still need full .htaccess content?

Comment: Yeah, that would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.(php|html) to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.(?:html?|php)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well... I only needed the first part though... :)

Comment: Right if you have `Options +MultiViews` then last 2 rules aren't needed for you.